# Alternative For IdentifierForVendor in ios7 Above

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode6, uniqueidentifier

I noticed that whenever I reinstall my app, the IdentifierForVendor keeps on changing. Is there a way for me to have the same identifier for my device? The thing is, I need to make sure that the identifier is the same because I have a backup system that allows user to re-download their progress even after deleting and reinstalling the app. The identifierForVendor isn't a reliable value. I also looked at advertisingIdentifier but it's also no good. By any chance, do you know of a string returned by Apple that I may use as an alternative? Or is there a way to generate the same string for a certain device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<del>The identifierForVendor is a reliable value, but only if the app has been downloaded from the app store, it won't change even if the user uninstalls and reinstall.</del>

EDIT: **This is no longer true, now when the app is downloaded from the apple store the identifierForVendor will be different if you remove the app and install it again, it even changed on app update due to an apple bug that it's fixed by now, but who knows if it will happen again. The identifierForVendor is not reliable if you want to use it's recommended to store it's value on the keychain**

When installing from xcode, ad-hoc distribution and even the new testflight betatesting it changes after uninstalls if you don't have another of your apps installed with the same bundle id base name (com.yourcompany.xxxxx, com.yourcompany.yyyyy,com.yourcompany.zzzzzz)

Comment: why the downvote? I assure you the identifierForVendor don't change when the app is downloaded form the app store, I have some apps whose behaviour relies on the identifierForVendor and I didn't have problems so far

Comment: really strange downvote, anyway upvoting. I think the reason was that identifierForVendor changes after reinstall...

Comment: it wasn't me who down voted. i'm sorry for that. so if it's downloaded from iTunes, it doesn't change. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Yes, if the app is downloaded from the app store it doesn't change, I have uninstalled and installed the app hundreds of times and I always get the same identifier with no other apps installed.

Comment: even if there's no other application with same bundle id base name in your device?

Comment: Yes, I've just tested again, deleted all my apps from the iPhone, downloaded the app from the app store, checked the identifierForVendor and I got the same identifier I have stored on my database and noted on the computer from previous tests

Comment: and please, can you remove the downvote? I've edited the answer, so you can change the vote

Comment: i think the vendor ID changes if the phone goes through an OS upgrade

Comment: no, I have the same I had on iOS 7. It didn't change when updated to iOS 8

Comment: I think the pint us that it is not _guaranteed_ to remain the same. If you assume that it will then you are mistaken.

Comment: RE: When installing from xcode, ad-hoc distribution and even the new testflight betatesting it changes after uninstalls if you don't have another of your apps installed with the same bundle id base name (com.yourcompany.xxxxx, com.yourcompany.yyyyy,com.yourcompany.zzzzzz)  - The IDFV is no longer changing when I delete the app and reinstall using xcode on a development device - and no longer changing when I delete the app and reinstall as adhoc from iTunes. (It used to change EVERY time when I used either of these methods)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other of your apps installed, even a test app will cause that the IDFV don't change.